# How to disable one input field when one is selected in AngularJS? (both using same ng-model)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, angularjs, django

Hi I have two input fields. input field A(drop-down) and input field B. Both of them are posting same value (same ng-model). What I need to achieve is when the user select one option from the dropdown button the second input field need to cleared. How can I do that using AngularJS? Am very new to AngularJS. Thanks in advance.

```
<table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><b>BB</b></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="input" ng-model="final_data.bb" readonly>
                    </div>
                </td>

                    <p align="center" ng-show="processing['update_ms']" ng-class="processing['update_mst'].class" ng-cloak>
                        {{ processing['update_ms'].msg }}
                    </p>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><b>InputA</b></span>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-change="get_mass(); disableMass() " ng-model="final_data.mas" ng-options="m as m for m in maslist" required ng-cloak>
                        </select> &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><b>InputB*</b></span>
                        <input class="form-control" ng-disabled="isSelected" ng-model="final_data.mas" type="input">&nbsp;
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about to create 2 different models for select input and input field and initialize them by nil. So you can:

```
<select ng-model='selectModel' ng-disabled='inputModel'>
...
</select>

<input type='text' ng-model='inputModel' ng-disabled='selectModel' />
```

And if you need to change original model by changing select and input models:

**html**

```
<select ng-model='selectModel' ng-disabled='inputModel' ng-change=syncModel(selectModel)>
...
</select>

<input type='text' ng-model='inputModel' ng-disabled='selectModel' ng-change=syncModel(selectModel)/>
```

**js**

```
$scope.originalModel = null;
$scope.syncModel = function (value) {
    $scope.originalModel = value;
}
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to clear another field:

```
$scope.syncModel = function (value) {
    $scope.originalModel = value;
    //clearing
    if (value == $scope.inputModel) 
        $scope.selectModel = null;
    else
        $scope.inputModel = null;
}
```

Dirty but easy

**UPDATE:**
Your code:

```
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><b>BB</b></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="input" ng-model="final_data.bb" readonly>
                    </div>
                </td>

                    <p align="center" ng-show="processing['update_ms']" ng-class="processing['update_mst'].class" ng-cloak>
                        {{ processing['update_ms'].msg }}
                    </p>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><b>InputA</b></span>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-change="get_mass(); syncModels(selectModel) " ng-model="selectModel" ng-options="m as m for m in maslist" required ng-cloak ng-disabled="inputModel">
                        </select> &nbsp;
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><b>InputB*</b></span>
                        <input class="form-control" ng-disabled="selectModel" ng-model="inputModel" ng-change="syncModels(inputModel)" type="input">&nbsp;
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**js**

```
$scope.selectModel = null;
$scope.inputModel = null;
$scope.syncModels = function (value) {
   $scope.final_data.mas = value;
   //clearing
   if (value == $scope.inputModel) 
      $scope.selectModel = null;
   else
      $scope.inputModel = null;
}
```

Comment: Andrew,But that will only disable right? What if I want to clear the field?

Comment: @GentleJoseph I've update answer. Dirty decision, but easy to understand and improvement

Comment: But Andrew, I need to use the same ng-model for both the input fields. Please see my updated question

Comment: @GentleJoseph I see, but in my answer in $scope.syncModel you can set your final_data.mas model to selected value. I mean your input and select have different models, but on change one of them you set your final_data.mas original model to selected or inputed value

Comment: Andrew, can you please update your answer if you dont mind :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense.

`ng-model` is real time representation of input fields' displayed value. At least for text input, the displayed text is always equal to its `ng-model` value.

I also have hard time figuring out your use case. What happens to the dropdown when the user type in input field?

Comment: Then it will call the ng-model and display a list of values. Updated my question

Comment: Are you looking for something like [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)?